# Insert date automatically on next row available using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to have an script to add weekly a timestamp (to use autocrat automatically) but to be entered in the next row each week.
I had:

```
function setDate() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Mailer!A5').setValue(new Date())

}
```

But that works with an specific cell, I need now to add something like an +1 row to be entered on the next available row of the specific column weekly (with a trigger).

Comment: What do you mean by "next row available"? Are you referring to a whole row or just to a blank cell in Column A?

Comment: The next available row in column A, for example A5 here:

A1 - Timestamp
A2 - 1/1/2017
A3 - 8/1/2017
A4 - 15/1/2017
A5 - *blank*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.getLastRow()` in the `Sheet` class to get the last empty Row and use that with `getRange(rownumber, columnumber)` to get the correct range. So provided the last row with any data will always have a timestamp (so you cannot have data in row 10 and expect the next timestamp to appear in row 8 with this method)

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Mailer');
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(new Date())
```

If you want to check only column `A` for the last value then before setting the new value you need to use `var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues()` and then use a `for` loop to look for the first empty `values[i][0]`

Comment: I got:
function setDate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Mailer');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(new Date());

}

but it does not work I didnt got the for values[i][0]

Comment: @JuanPabloMarroquinOcampo edited out the typo in my answer and noticed I forgot to add a `+1` either in line 2 or line 3, as `.getLastRow()` returns last row with data, so you need to add 1 to it. The last of the 3 rows you need is `sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(new Date())`. If you do not intend to look for an empty spot then you don't need the `var values` part, it's literally just those 3 lines of code to add a date to the last empty row.